# Why does the Restler3 'vendor' folder need to be on site root?

Tags: php, .htaccess, restler

I downloaded Restler3 a few days ago and while tinkering with it, I decided it was a good idea to move the 'vendor' folder outside site root.
At first everything seemed fine, but then I noticed that for example the /math/sum/* example didn't work anymore (as shown here : http://restler3.luracast.com/examples/_002_minimal/readme.html

Ok, so instead of moving it outside the root folder, i moved it in a subfolder, and strangely enough the same result. url's that are like api.domain.com/math/sum/1/2/3/4 that take a variable amount of parameters, just stop working, until i put the 'vendor' folder back in the site root.

Now this may be obvious why to some of you, to me it is not. I always write code that never relies on it's location relatively to something else in order to prevent incompatibilities.
The code from Restler looks solid enough so I can't imagine they didn't do the same thing.

Is it maybe something on my server? Is it perhaps something with the advised .htaccess? (I always hated those as I don't really fully understand them)

The .htaccess looks like this :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %ˆ{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can someone maybe shed some light on this for me please, ie enlighten me? I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vendor folder need not be and should not be on the publicly accessible.

when you move vendor folder make sure you move composer.json along and run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to make sure the autoload.php is upto date